# Change markdown Bullets to html in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

At the moment I have a function

```
export function markdownToHtml(mdText) {
  const toHTML = mdText
    .replace(/^### (.*$)/gim, "<h3>$1</h3>") // h3 tag
    .replace(/^## (.*$)/gim, "<h2>$1</h2>") // h2 tag
    .replace(/^# (.*$)/gim, "<h1>$1</h1>") // h1 tag
    .replace(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/gim, "<b>$1</b>") // bold text
    .replace(/\*(.*)\*/gim, "<i>$1</i>") // italic text
    .replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gim, "<a href='$2'>$1</a>") // link
  return toHTML.trim() // using trim method to remove whitespace
}
```

where I am parsing some of the Markdown styles to HTML but I'm missing the regex to parse bullet points.

any Idea?
(not using a dependecy is better)

Comment: How is not using a module/dependency better? The problem will already have been solved.

Comment: "Missing"? Where'd it go? What's the specific issue? Noting that if you want it to end up being *good* HTML you'll also need to iterate and put the list items inside an actual list. When you're dealing w/ Markdown, "not using a dependency" is not better. It's harder than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

It does not wrap in UL

```js
function markdownToHtml(mdText) {
  const toHTML = mdText.split("\n").map(text => text
    .trim() // using trim method to remove whitespace
    .replace(/^### (.*$)/i, "<h3>$1</h3>") // h3 tag
    .replace(/^## (.*$)/i, "<h2>$1</h2>") // h2 tag
    .replace(/^# (.*$)/i, "<h1>$1</h1>") // h1 tag
    .replace(/^\* (.*$)/i, "<li>$1</li>") // <li> tag
    .replace(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/i, "<b>$1</b>") // bold text
    .replace(/\*(.*)\*/i, "<i>$1</i>") // italic text
    .replace(/\*(.*)\*/i, "<i>$1</i>") // italic text
    .replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/i, "<a href='$2'>$1</a>")) // link
  return toHTML.join("\n") 
}

console.log(markdownToHtml(`### Title\n* *Bold bullet*`))
```